# Tabbing into a radio group moves its focus on the last radio button instead of the first

Tags: html, radio-button, radio-group

I am trying to create an accessible credit card selection on a payment page of an e-commerce site. Here is markup that I have:

```css
.cc__card {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  position: relative;
}

.cc__card>input:focus+label {
  outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-style: auto;
}

.cc__card>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cc__icon {
  height: 35px;
  width: 54px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}

.cc__icon.not-selected {
  opacity: 0.45;
}

.cc__icon.selected {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.cc__icon--visa {
  background-image: url("../images/cc-icon-visa.png");
}

.cc__icon--mastercard {
  background-image: url("../images/cc-icon-mastercard.png");
}

.cc__icon--amex {
  background-image: url("../images/cc-icon-amex.png");
}

.cc__icon--discover {
  background-image: url("../images/cc-icon-discover.png");
}

.cc__icon--other {
  background-image: url("../images/cc-icon-other.png");
}
```

```html
<label for="cardType">Select your Card Type</label>

<div class="cc__card">
  <input id="cc-icon-other" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="other" tabindex="1" />
  <label class="cc__icon cc__icon--other" for="cc-icon-other">
    <span class="sr-only">Other</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="cc__card">
  <input id="cc-icon-visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
  <label class="cc__icon cc__icon--visa" for="cc-icon-visa">
    <span class="sr-only">Visa</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="cc__card">
  <input id="cc-icon-master-card" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
  <label class="cc__icon cc__icon--mastercard" for="cc-icon-master-card">
    <span class="sr-only">MasterCard</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="cc__card">
  <input id="cc-icon-discover" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="discover" />
  <label class="cc__icon cc__icon--discover" for="cc-icon-discover">
    <span class="sr-only">Discover</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="cc__card">
  <input id="cc-icon-american-express" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="amex" />
  <label class="cc__icon cc__icon--amex" for="cc-icon-american-express">
    <span class="sr-only">American Express</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

But when I tab into the radio group the last radio button is focused instead of the first as shown in the image below:

[image]

I need the first radio button to be focused on when the user tabs into the radio group. In the latest versions of Chrome and FF the focus moves to the last radio button (American Express) but in IE 11 it moves to second radio button (Visa).

The only JS used here is an onchange event handler that just reads the id attribute of the selected radio button.

Can someone please provide any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a radio button is a group that functions as a single element since it retains only a single value. Tabbing to a radio group will bring you to the first item and then using the arrow keys you navigate within the group.

> - Focus can move to a radio group via:
>
>   - The Tab key
>   - An Access Key or mnemonic targeting the label
>   - Activation of the label (through Assistive Technology mechanism)
> - The Tab key moves focus between radio button groups and other widgets.
> - When focus is on the group and when no radio button is selected:
>
>   - Tab key press moves focus to the first radio button in the group, but     does not select the radio button.
>   - Shift+Tab key press moves focus to the last radio button in the    group, but does not select the radio button.
> - When focus moves to the group in which a radio button is selected, pressing Tab and Shift+Tab keys move focus to the radio button that is
>     checked.
> - Up Arrow and Down Arrow keys move focus and selection.
>
>   - Up Arrow key press moves    focus and selection forward through the radio buttons in the group.    If the first radio button has
>       focus, then focus and selection move to    the last radio button in
>       the group.
>   - Down Arrow key press moves focus and selection backward through the radio buttons in the group. If the last radio button has focus,
>       then focus and selection move to the first radio button in the group.
>   - Space Bar key press checks the radio button that currently has focus.
> - When re-entering the group, focus returns to the point of previous focus (the item with selection set).
> - Pressing the Tab key exits the group and moves focus to the next form control.
> - Pressing the Shift+Tab keys exits the group and moves focus to the previous form control.

There is also a [jQuery](https://gist.github.com/jonathanconway/899a0856a8b16245cca3) plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that but I am not able to figure out why the focus moves to last radio button instead of the first in Chrome and FF and to the second in IE 11. Any ideas on this ? Or any way to force the order ?